# Python dictionary selection

Tags: python

I have a dictionary for which the value represent a range of number:

```
{'1': [0, 11], '2': [12, 23], '3': [24, 35], '4': [36, 41], '5': [42, 47], '6': [48, 53], '7': [54, 58], '8': [59, 64], '9': [65, 70], '10': [71, None]}
```

If I want to search for a specific value, lets say 33...
How can I get the index matching the value range in which it is contained?

I would expect to return the index 3 since 33 is contained between 24 and 35 in the example above from the keyPair `'3': [24, 35]`.

Comment: Why should the output be 3 when the input is 33?

Comment: Are you saying you would like to search the dictionary for a value, then return the key associated to that value?

Side note: Dictionaries aren't indexed. It's unclear if you're talking about the index of the list inside the dictionary or the key for the dictionary.

Comment: Yes thats correct, they are ranges of values I just update it as I spotted an error.

Comment: For example 33 is in the range 24-35 so returns index 3.

Comment: 33 doesn't exist anywhere in that

Comment: @roganjosh it is between 24,35.

Comment: It seems a straightforward exercise, so how and where in your code are you stuck? We cannot help if you don't share your code.

Comment: Ugh. Please be specific. Please [edit] the question to state that they are ranged. It's frustrating to review a question and find that we're supposed to divine the intent

Comment: I think I understand. Typing up the code right now and will send it as a response.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to handle the None if the other int is your i value:

```
i = 33
for k, v in d.items():
    if None not in v:
        if i in range(v[0],v[1]+1):
            print(k)
    elif i in v:
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but this code will work from what I understand.

```
test = {'1': [0, 11], 
        '2': [12, 23], 
        '3': [24, 35], 
        '4': [36, 41], 
        '5': [42, 47], 
        '6': [48, 53], 
        '7': [54, 58], 
        '8': [59, 64], 
        '9': [65, 70], 
        '10': [71, None]}
objective_val = 33

for key, value in test.items():
    if objective_val >= value[0] and objective_val <= value[1]:
        print(key)
```

or

```
for key, value in test.items():
    if objective_val in range(value[0],value[1]+1):
        print(key)
```

Comment: The line `for key, value in test.items():` will iterate over each key in the dictionary then the if statement checks that it's in each range then prints the key when the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a numpy solution

```
import numpy as np

d = {'1': [0, 11],
     '2': [12, 23],
 '3': [24, 35],
 '4': [36, 41],
 '5': [42, 47],
 '6': [48, 53],
 '7': [54, 58],
 '8': [59, 64],
 '9': [65, 70],
 '10': [71, None]}

# get labels and bin edges
labels, bins = zip(*d.items())

# get bin boundaries in a form to use in digitize function
bin_boundaries = [bin[0] for bin in bins[:-1]] + [bins[-1][0], np.inf]

# get bin number as an offset
index = np.digitize(33, bin_boundaries) - 1

# the answer
labels[index]
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say this function takes a dictionary `d` and the value you're looking for `v`.

```
def find_range_key(d, v):
    for key, vrange in d.items():
        if vrange[0] <= v <= vrange[1]:
            return key
    return -1
```

Comment: I'm gonna hedge betsthat this throws an error because you didn't call `.items()`

Comment: yep, fixed it now.